# android kotlin all Fragments are called

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having problems that all my fragments are called when the application start so when I do toast on the the second fragment it appear on the first fragment

here is my activity code

```
class HomePage : AppCompatActivity() {

    var adapter: FPA? = null
    val manager = supportFragmentManager

    private lateinit var drawer: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(null)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page_act)

        adapter = FPA(supportFragmentManager)
        container.adapter = adapter

        container.addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))

        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))
    }

    class FPA(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            if(position==0 )
                return TrainingForSale()
            else if(position==1)
                return Shops()
            else
                return  Health()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 3
        }
    }

    fun ShowFramentShops (){
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction ()
        val fragmet = Shops()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragmet)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

and here is my fragment  pages 
fragment (1)

```
class Shops : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.shops_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(null);
        //UserInformation.TrainingFilter=""
        //UserInformation.TrainingList.clear()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(null)
        Toast.makeText(activity,"Shopes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

my second fragment

```
class Health : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.health_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(null);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Toast.makeText(activity,"Health", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

So when I run the the app both toast appears in the same page

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewPager` will not only create the current page, but also the some before or after. With [`setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) you can adapt these values a little.

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: really thanks for your answer but its not working for me :S .. so basically now if i swipe to the second page the code from the third fragment will be called and if i swiped from the third fragment to the second fragment the code form the first fragment will be called

Comment: Just assume the fragments are always there. It's possible that you cannot adapt it to never pre-create any fragment. If you need information about when a fragment is active have a look at all the other life-cycle events. This behavior is there for a reason. And no matter what you want to do, you can do it differently to using `onViewCreated()`.